# A real world example of using #define in C#?

Tags: c#

I know that `#define` in `C#` lets you define a symbol to be used as the expression passed to an `#if` directive, and that the expression will evaluate to `true`.

But I can't think of any real use for this feature, do anyone knows a real use for it?

Comment: `DEBUG` comes to mind

Comment: Check this out [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: It's useless, it's just there for kicks.

Comment: @MarnixvanValen, please explain more

Comment: @Hohinhime, sorry, this is not useful for me

Comment: @MohammedA.Fadil I've added an answer to explain.

Answer (score 6):

There simply aren't a whole lot of uses for it.

With `#define` you can *only* define constants for conditional compilation, and you would normally control these from the Build configurations.

Answer (score 4):

The most common use of a compile-time symbol is `DEBUG` which is defined by default through the Debug build configuration, not using a `#define` statement. In practice all compile-time symbols I've seen are defined through build configurations.

This is mostly due to the way source files are structured in C#. In C++ some header files (.h) typically contain a lot of #defines for things like platform dependent configuration. C# doesn't support including files into a source file. In addition, the (largely) platform independent nature of .NET eliminates the need for a lot of the defines required to make C++ code compile.

Further more, [the scope of a symbol declared using `#define`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x(v=vs.80).aspx) is limited to the source file it is in. Effective use of a symbol throughout a project requires the `#define` to be repeated in all files it is used in, making it very hard to maintain consistency.

As Henk Holterman [pointed out already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9972350/64096), the only maintainable way to define a global compile-time symbol is through the build configuration because these symbols are defined once and available to *all* files in the project.

Having said that, `#define` can be useful to verify conditional compilation is working as expected. If you set a `#define` at the top of a .cs file in Visual Studio the active code will be highlighted and inactive code is greyed-out. You could also use it to enable debug-only code in a single file, for example while troubleshooting a problem.

So, to answer your question, there are no good uses I know of of the #define statement in C# in production code but it can be a handy tool for testing.

Answer (score 2):

```
#if DEBUG
    var jwriter = new VerboseJsonWriter(0);
#else
    var jwriter = new TerseJsonWriter();
#endif
```

The first one formats JSON in a pretty way, with indentations, everything on new line, etc. So that it's human readable for debugging.

The second one places everything in one line with no whitespace whatsoever, so that in production bandwidth is used optimally and things load quickly.

Comment: @AndrewCooper - those are usually passed from the build process, as already noted in Henk Holterman's answer. But this still does illustrate a use for such a symbol.

Comment: Yes, but the OP wasn't asking about the use of symbols, he was asking about we're you'd use the `#define` directive.

Comment: @AndrewCooper - To me it's not clear if the OP is asking about the `#define`, or where you use these symbols at all.

Comment: @Vilx-, actually I am asking about both, that is why I said a real world example, for example "I used '#define' to define... which I used to... in my application"

Comment: -1 this is an example of #if/#else - the question asks for an example of #define.

Answer (score 1):

`#define` as a preprocessor directive directly inserted in a C# source file is not of great utility.
You could set a prepocessor variable in this way:

```
#define PRO_VERSION
```

Then, if you want to have two version of your application (a PRO paid version and a FREE version), you could encapsulate the code reserved to the PRO version with the prepocessor directive `#if PRO_VERSION`

```
...
#if PRO_VERSION 
    SomethingOnlyInProVersion(); 
#elif
    SomethingOnlyInFreeVersion(); 
#endif 
...


#if PRO_VERSION 
public void SomethingOnlyInProVersion()
{
}
#elif
public void SomethingOnlyFreeVersion()
{
}
#endif
```

But all of this will fall short. If you want to compile your code without the PRO_VERSION you need to remove the `#define` because you cannot assign a value like in old C compiler (like `#define PRO_VERSION = 0`. Another problem of the directive is its visibility. The scope is limited to the current file. VisualStudio introduces the Configuration Manager just to resolve this kind of problems. There you can create different `Configurations` where each has its own set of symbols defined that could be checked and applied to the whole solution or to the individual projects without touching the source files.

Comment: @MattDavey, not sure to understand you, but very few of the answers here could be considered 'real world example'. At least I have provided a reason to use the directive. Could you enlighten me?

Comment: @Steve I think the OP is asking for someones real world experience of having used `#define` "in the wild". A theoretical example of how it *could* be used doesn't provide much value over the MSDN documentation.

Comment: @MattDavey, I have used the same 'theoretical' code above for a program of mine. It works well.

Comment: @Steve did you use `#define` in your program or did you set compilation symbols in the build configuration?

Comment: @MattDavey, I have only one place where this distinction was needed so I have used directly in the source code. I know that is better to use the Configuration Manager, but this is not the point.

Comment: The build configuration is irrelevant to this question as the OP is specifically asking about `#define` - and it seems you do have a real world example of using `#define`. At the moment the answer reads more like a theoretical "you could do this" whereas the OP is looking for a "we did this and this is why" - with a couple of minor edits I'd be happy to revert my downvote :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14875/discussion-between-mattdavey-and-steve)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a debug logger in your code which you don't want to use in your release code so you should use `#define`:

```
#if DEBUG_LOG
DebuggingTool.Activate();
#else
DebuggingTool.Deactivate();
#endif
```

And in VS 2010 you can add on the build tab `conditional compilation symbols` to add global symbols

Comment: No `#define` used or needed here.

Comment: I added a line below the code saying you should add the symbols from the build tab of project properties: Conditional compilation Symbols

Comment: -1 this is an example of #if/#else - the question asks for a real world example of #define

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a warning as why NOT to use it.

If you use a tool like resharper that allows renaming it will not pick up renaming of variables etc if they are within a block that is not used by the current configuration but everything will compile.

So if you do a refactor for some code that has a condition that is applied in debug and then check it in as everything has compiled, it does not mean that code will compile in another mode such as release.

It may not be the end of the world as your build server would (should) pick it up, but as we all know, breaking the build means you owe beer to the rest of the team!

Answer (score 1):

I've only ever had one legitimate use for it, and that was for unit testing methods which had a `Conditional` attribute:

```
public class Foo()
{
    [Conditional("XYZ")]
    public void Bar()
    {
        // Something cool...
    }
}
```

I had to add the `#define` directive to be able to unit test the method:

```
#define XYZ
public class FooTests
{
    [Test]
    public void BarShouldDoSomethingCool()
    {
        var subject = new Foo();

        subject.Bar();

        // assert something cool happened
    }
}
```

Without the `#define` directive, the method would not have been called in the unit tests, resulting in either inconclusive or failing tests.